# java multi-thread producer-consumer confusing result

Tags: java, multithreading

I am a beginner in Java multithreading. Here is a demonstration code about the producer-consumer model and the `wait`, `notifyAll` methods, but I find the results very difficult to understand.

```java
public class ProducerConsumerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SharedResource sharedResource = new SharedResource();

        Thread producerThread = new Thread(new Producer(sharedResource));
        Thread consumerThread = new Thread(new Consumer(sharedResource));

        producerThread.start();
        consumerThread.start();

    }
}


class SharedResource {
    private int content;

    private boolean available = false;


    public synchronized void put(int value) {
        while (available) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        content = value;
        available = true;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized int get() {
        while (!available) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        available = false;
        notifyAll();
        return content;
    }

}

class Producer implements Runnable {

    private final SharedResource resource;

    Producer(SharedResource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            resource.put(i);
            System.out.println("Produced: " + i);
        }


    }
}


class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private final SharedResource resource;

    Consumer(SharedResource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Consumed: " + resource.get());
        }

    }
}
```

The actual running results are as follows.

```
Produced: 0
Produced: 1
Consumed: 0
Consumed: 1
Produced: 2
Produced: 3
Consumed: 2
Consumed: 3
Consumed: 4
Produced: 4
Produced: 5
Produced: 6
Consumed: 5
Consumed: 6
Consumed: 7
Produced: 7
Consumed: 8
Produced: 8
Produced: 9
Consumed: 9
```

Such results are outrageous. I believe the results should be the producer's `put` and the consumer's `get` executed in succession. In other words, the results should be like this.

```
Produced: 0
Consumed: 0
Produced: 1
Consumed: 1
...
```

I believe the process should be like this:

- The producer executes `put(0)`,
- and at this moment `available` is `false`. Then, `available` is set to `true`, and the value of content is also set to `0`.
- Following this, `notifyAll()` is executed.
- At this point, the consumer thread might not have entered the waiting state yet, but this does not significantly impact the result.
- Next, `put(1)` should be executed. At this time, since the value of `available` is `true`, it enters the while loop, and then the `wait()` method is executed.
- At this point, the producer thread becomes waiting and releases the lock. The consumer thread, upon acquiring the lock and seeing that `available` is `true`, does not enter the while loop.
- It then sets `available` to `false` and calls `notifyAll()` to put the producer thread in a blocked state, while returning the value of content.
- Suppose the producer thread acquires the lock at this point and continues to execute `put(1)` (even if the consumer thread acquires the lock and executes `get(1)`, it doesn't matter because it will enter the while loop and call the `wait()` method, allowing the producer thread to continue executing `put(1)`),

and so on in this cycle.

Additionally, there are even more outrageous outcomes; this time, the result of the consumer thread was even printed out first, like this:

```
Consumed: 0
Produced: 0
Produced: 1
Produced: 2
Consumed: 1
Consumed: 2
Consumed: 3
...
```

Can someone explain what exactly is going on with these results? Why are they different from what I expected?

Comment: It can be that the producer after returning from `put(0)` is suspended before it had time to create the string "Produced: 0" and print it out and that the consumer therefore can call `get()` **and** print out "Consumed: 0" before the producer prints out "Produced: 0".

Comment: To reinforce Thomas's comment, threads run asynchronously and can interleave exactly like you show in your output.  The behavior is not outrageous it is normal and expected.  This is all threads, including OS threads, not just Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your problem is not what happens inside the `synchronized` methods - it is what happens outside of those methods.

Actions outside of the `synchronized` methods are not ordered between the threads.

One possible valid sequence is:

- the producer thread calls `put(0)`, then writes out "Produced: 0", then calls `put(1)` and has to wait for the consumer
- the consumer calls `get()`, but is suspended right after returning from `get()` - before it can print out anything
- the producer finishes the `put(1)`, then writes out "Produced: 1", then calls `put(2)` and must again wait for the consumer
- only now the consumer can write out "Consumed: 0"

Another possible valid sequence is:

- the producer thread calls `put(0)` and after that it is suspended before it can print out anything
- the consumer thread calls `get()`, then writes out "Consumed: 0", then calls `get()` again and must wait for the producer
- the producer is now resumed, prints out "Produced: 0", then calls `put(1)`

Comment: To summarize, after executing `put(0)`, I originally thought that `System.out.println("Produced: " + i);` would be executed **immediately**, but it wasn't. Instead, the producer thread was suspended right away, and then the consumer thread started, which is why `Consumer 0` was printed first. I had assumed that once a thread starts executing, it would continue until it's suspended (like with the wait() method here). However, in this case, right after the producer thread completed `put(0)`, the CPU immediately switched to executing the consumer thread, which was quite surprising.